# Setting seperator clip path ( polygon ) responsive

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm pretty new to clip paths with css, but what im trying to do it make a clip path separator for 2 background colors. I tried to look up if someone already did something similar but i didn't find it. I'm using Tailwindcss and just regulair CSS with HTML

This is how far I got so far :
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Flidiot/pen/ZEJMyXe)

Code:

```
<div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 w-full ">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 ">
        <div class="py-12 px-4">
            <h3 class="text-2xl text-white font-bold">Lorum ipsum</h3>
            <p class="text-white mt-4">Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="py-12 px-4  z-10 flex items-center">
            <ul class="mx-auto space-y-4 text-white text-xl">
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="py-12  px-4 z-10 flex items-center">
            <ul class=" mx-auto space-y-4 text-white text-xl">
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
                <li class="flex">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>
                    Lorum ipsum
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" hidden md:flex absolute h-full w-3/5 top-0 right-0 bg-yellow-300 " style="clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 5% 0%); -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 5% 0%);"></div>
```

My problem now is thats its not responsive. You can see the text overlapping once you go down in screen resolution.

Can someone give me a bit of directions on where to go from here? I'm not sure if I'm going the right direction or if my code needs to change completely.

This is the result im trying to achieve[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the aspect ratio of the whole changes with different viewports/devices so the % measurements needed to maintain the same angle of slope change and would require some calculation (e.g. in JS) to maintain.

One alternative is to use a feature in CSS where it will maintain a slope. That is linear-gradient.

This snippet introduces two new classes. bgSlope paints a background with a slope and bgDual ensures that the yellow color extends right across the parent element, however much the overall width compared to the centered content.

Of course, there will have to  be some alteration when the viewport gets so narrow that the second two columns move beneath, otherwise you'll get a funny angle, but I don't know what you want to do anyway with the coloring on a narrow device.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .bgSlope {
      background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, rgba(252, 211, 77) 62.5%, transparent 62.5% 100%);
    }
    
    .bgDual {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(209, 213, 219) 0 70%, rgba(252, 211, 77) 70% 100%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w-full relative bgDual">

    <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 w-full ">
      <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 bgSlope">
        <div class="py-12 px-4">
          <h3 class="text-2xl text-white font-bold">Lorum ipsum</h3>
          <p class="text-white mt-4">Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum Some more lorum ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="py-12 px-4  z-10 flex items-center">
          <ul class="mx-auto space-y-4 text-white text-xl">
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="py-12  px-4 z-10 flex items-center">
          <ul class=" mx-auto space-y-4 text-white text-xl">
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
            <li class="flex">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-8 w-8 mr-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m6 2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                        </svg> Lorum ipsum
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is what im looking for thanks alot! Seems like you made a little typo though in your bgSlope class. IF you fix it ill approve this answer :) 

see your position relative. 

or just add the relative class to the same element bgSlope is on.

Comment: Thanks for spotting! This setting isn't needed, I tend to prefix properties with 'r' (for redundant) when I don't think I need them but am testing that out and obviously I forgot to remove it. I've removed it now.

Comment: ahh good to know. I see now that nothing happend when its removed yeah :P anyway approved the question and thx again :)